# Skewed labels in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I was drawing a diagram on natural transformation using tikzcd. However, I don't know why the output was "skewed":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\mathscr{O}(X)^{op}
\arrow[r, bend left, "\Lambda A"]
\arrow[r, bend right, swap, "\Lambda A'"]
\arrow[r, phantom, bend left, shift right=0.2ex, ""{name=U}]
\arrow[r, phantom, bend right, shift left=0.2ex, swap, ""{name=D}]
&\textbf{Set}
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D, "\Lambda f"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

I got the following skewed output:
[image]

Now when compared to a similar code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\mathscr{A}
\arrow[r, bend left, "F"]
\arrow[r, bend right, swap, "G"]
\arrow[r, phantom, bend left, shift right=0.2ex, ""{name=U}]
\arrow[r, phantom, bend right, shift left=0.2ex, swap, ""{name=D}]
&\mathscr{B}
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D, "\alpha"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

And it give a beautiful output:

[image]

Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the height and width of `\mathscr{O}(X)^{op}` is different from the height and width of `\textbf{Set}`.

[image]

`tikz-cd` bends the arrows unequally when those boxes aren't the same size, which affects the positioning of the arrow labels and the placement of `U` and `D`.

One way to give `\textbf{Set}` the exact same box as `\mathscr{O}(X)^{op}` is to `\rlap` the `\textbf{Set}` with an invisible `\mathscr{O}(X)^{op}` using `\phantom`.

[image]

I added a space before `Set` because I thought it looked better that way. You can remove or adjust to your liking. Also, instead of using the two phantom arrows, you can `name` the space above or below the arrow, as I did in the code below. If you want the center arrow to be closer to the curved arrows you can use `shorten <=` and `shorten >=` with negative values.

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\mathscr{O}(X)^{op}
\arrow[r, bend left, "\Lambda A", ""{name=U, below}]
\arrow[r, bend right, swap, "\Lambda A'", ""{name=D, above}]
&\rlap{\textbf{\ Set}}\phantom{\mathscr{O}(X)^{op}}
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D, "\Lambda f"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

Answer (score 2):

With manual tweak of arrows labels positions:

```
\documentclass{standalone}%article
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
%\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathscr{O}(X)^{op}
    \ar[r, bend  left, pos=0.47, "\Lambda A"]
    \ar[r, bend right, pos=0.47, swap, "\Lambda A'"]
    \ar[r, phantom, bend left, ""{name=U}]
    \ar[r, phantom, bend right, pos=0.47, ""{name=D}]
        &   \textbf{Set}
                \ar[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D, "\Lambda f"]
\end{tikzcd}
%\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My proposal using `xy` package (for the commutative diagrams) with the option `2cell`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[cmtip,all,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix@R=3pc@C=3pc{\mathscr{O}(X)^{op}\rtwocell<7>^{\Lambda A}_{\Lambda A'}{\mkern15mu\Lambda f} &\textbf{Set}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: You really like the xy package, right? :)